# Authentication Error when resolving dependencies from spring repo

Tags: spring, repository, gradle

Having trouble resolving gradle dependencies.  This worked previously.  Is there any reason why it would be  Unauthorized other than a config problem on Spring's side?

```
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.20/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.pom]
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.20/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.pom]
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.20/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.pom]
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot/org/apache/tiles/tiles-request-servlet-wildcard/1.0.2/tiles-request-servlet-wildcard-1.0.2.pom]
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/org/apache/tiles/tiles-request-servlet-wildcard/1.0.2/tiles-request-servlet-wildcard-1.0.2.pom]
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/apache/tiles/tiles-request-servlet-wildcard/1.0.2/tiles-request-servlet-wildcard-1.0.2.pom]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a config issue on Spring's side. If you look at the error you get in a browser

> This request requires HTTP authentication (User anonymous is not
>   permitted to deploy 'mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.20/COPYING' into
>   'repo1-cache:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.20/COPYING'.).

there is some caching (into repo1-cache) or something that's failing.

Comment: Seems that way, any idea where I should report this?  Just spring forums?

Comment: @AshMcConnell Yeah, that sounds appropriate to me